# Ubuntu 12.10 Copy Virtual Hosts From One Server to Another

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.10

I'd like to copy my sites-available and sites-enabled folders from one server and move them to my new server without typing them all out again.  Is there a fast way to do this?  Maybe I could copy them to my desktop and then back to the new server?  I don't know that commands to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `rsync`?

On server1:

```
rsync -aP /etc/apache2/sites-available you@<ip_of_server2>:/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Comment: when I try that I get:

Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]

Comment: You probably need to put your public key (the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on server`) in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server 2.